# Calendar class confusion

Tags: java, calendar

I was playing with the Calendar class and got some confusing results:

```
    Calendar thisCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    thisCal.clear();

    thisCal.set(2012,12,8);

    System.out.println("Year is: " + thisCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Month is: " + thisCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    System.out.println("Day of Month is: " + thisCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

The output:

Year is: 2013

Month is: 0

Day of Month is: 8

Confused I am!

Comment: Javadoc you'll read and confused no longer you'll be, Yoda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MONTH` field is zero based (inherited from some POSIX API, I think). So you're setting it to the 13th month of 2012, which it interprets as the first month (with number 0) of 2013.

If you set the `lenient` property to `false`, it would throw an Exception instead.

Answer (score 2):

Month numbering starts from 0. More details [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the API doc of Calendar.

Month starts at ZERO.

Therefore, if you set 12 as month, it is in fact the "13th month", which cause the "strange" result